# Why was I suspended from suggested edits review on a closed question?

Tags: discussion, review-suspension

I was randomly suspended earlier this morning for incorrectly handling [this closed question edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/31628646).

> The following tasks were handled incorrectly:
>
> - https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/31628646
>
> You chose Approve. The edit(s) made the post worse and should have had the Reject action applied.

---

One of the other reviewers wanted to reject it because it was deviating from the original intent of the post. I disagree with this, because it adds some clarifying details without really changing what was the intended meaning of the question.

The edit also does reply to one of the answers, but I thought it was still worth adding the clarification there. I would have wanted to cut those parts out, but there was no "improve edit yourself" button. Even if this was a reason to reject the edit, the given reason was because it conflicted with the author.

The question originally was closed for needing more focus, and the edit doesn't address that, so I decided to keep it closed.

---

What's wrong with my reasoning for this edit? I haven't failed any suggested edit audits either (though they are easy to find; they make no sense when I read them).

Also, if this is important, I was suspended once for 2 days a few years ago. I do take full responsibility for that time, but I do fully read through all the reviews now.

Comment: Randomly? I don’t think so.

Comment: @yivi it doesn't say I failed anything else. I don't feel like one fail would be enough for getting suspended.

Comment: This was a manual suspension by a moderator. It wasn't random, and it wasn't based on any audit failures. (I have not yet assessed whether or not I agree with the decision; just stating a fact.)

Comment: I'm concerned that you would approve an edit which adds all that unneeded commentary. "First answer is very disappointing since it is referring to different package with similar name - something about halos. Check the links below. And frankly, I don't know the difference between those two packages either. It seems to me, that pytesseract is just a wrapper and you need to install tesseract first and that tesserac contains the command line program tesseract in itself." It's primarily commenting on existing answers, with a little bit of "me either", and part of an answer(?)

Comment: The *first thing* is that edits shouldn't start with "EDIT:". If you want to see what a post looked like before, check the revision history, meta remarks like "EDIT" or "UPDATE" have no place in a post. We want posts to read natural, not like a patchwork of different snippets of text. Which the rest of the edit *also fails at* because it's just a comment edited into the post, not made as a natural part of the post.

Comment: "I disagree with this .." - You might disagree but you would be approving an edit that shouldn't be approving, which is the reason you were suspended from approving edits. The edit is a "reply" replies shouldn't be edits to questions.  Edits should add the word "edit" to the answer/question.  **The edit was wrongfully accepted and rightfully reverted to it's original revision.** If you were suspended from edits for 2 days it means you failed an audit, this time around, a moderator did it. Your claim you have not failed audits isn't a factual statement.  **Everyone has at least once**

Comment: @SecurityHound I hit 2k pretty recently, I don't remember failing any in this queue (I have in other queues). I understand the mistake but I don't think one should be enough to be suspended either.

Comment: You said you had been review suspended in the past for 2 days. That’s just about the automatic timeframe for multiple audit failures

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's break down the edit you approved:

> The author is asking what is the difference between those two

Now the question author looks like a lunatic for referring to themselves in third person.

> First answer is very disappointing

With this, it makes it look like it is written *after* the answers, which reads like nonsense.

> And frankly, I don't know the difference between those two packages either

This part, combined with the third-person note, enforces the perception that the author developed a split personality disorder in between revisions.

> you need to install tesseract first

This now makes the question address readers as if they needed to do that.

Not to mention the "EDIT" prefix noise, as well as an non-descriptive edit summary, 50% of which is casting an opinion on answers instead of describing changes made:

> misleading and useless answers. Making this question more focused.

As for the rejection reason used by the rejecting reviewer (the *only* reviewer who did the right thing), while, admittedly, a more appropriate rejection reason would be "Attempt to reply", "No improvement", or "This edit causes harm", it is *no reason to take the opposite action*.

Comment: As the reject reviewer, I do agree that "Attempt to reply" would have been a better choice of reason, although the edit does also deviate from the original intent of the post in that it adds a bunch of content attributed to the author that the author did not write and does not necessarily agree with (we, for instance, have no idea what the author's opinion of the answers are).

Comment: @pppery oh, sure, I do not even think this was an invalid reason - I think the 3 proposed in the post describe the harm the edit does a bit better, but I do see how one could choose "Conflicts with author's intent" here.

Comment: Perhaps it was a way to circumvent the [50 reputation points threshold for comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/)?

Comment: The reasons to reject an edit are finite, sometimes an edit is just bad, and doesn’t necessarily fit in one of the canned responses. That doesn’t mean the edit should be approved.